# Why is my Laravel Inertia Lambda rendering pages inside nested modals?

Tags: laravel, aws-lambda, inertiajs

I have a Laravel app that works fine locally using Docker/Sail. However when I deploy that app to an AWS Lambda, it doesn't function in the same way. Once running as a Lambda, every time I navigate to a new page, the new page loads in a nested modal. My installation is pretty vanilla. Any idea as to why this would break as a Lambda, but behave differently running locally on Docker?

[image: Pages infinite nesting in modals]

As I first starting debugging this, I did notice that request header key cases didn't match. For instance, `Content-Type` when running locally and `content-type` when running in a Lambda. Some of the middleware seem to check for certain header keys, but they were typed with upper cased words in code.

Comment: Is the `X-Inertia` header sent in?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @CleanCode's comment, you need to add the following headers:

- x-inertia
- x-inertia-version

If you are using serverless, just add those two here:

- serverless.yml -> constructs: -> website: -> forwardedHeaders:

Or you can go to your cloudfront console, under behaviors tab, add these two to your origin request policy

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I won't be able to verify your answer right away, but I will give it a try when I get a chance. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).